# How to show desktop pager in KDE for one virtual desktop

Tags: plasma, kde5, pager, virtual-desktop

I have KDE5 Plasma with one virtual desktop. I tried to show a desktop pager in panel for one virtual desktop, but without success — by default, the pager will only display when there is more than one virtual desktop.
In KDE4, I could change the script at `/usr/share/kde4/apps/plasma/packages/org.kde.pager/contents/ui/main.qml` to always show the widget by commenting this line:

```
visible: repeater.count > 1
```

But in KDE5, the script is different and I don't know how to change it to show the widget when there is only one virtual desktop. The new location of the script is `/usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.pager/contents/ui/main.qml`.

Does anyone know how to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the issue with another widget on recommendation called [Pagermod](https://store.kde.org/p/1167789/).

Answer (score 0):

In the script at `/usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.pager/contents/ui/main.qml`, look for the line

```
Plasmoid.status: pagerModel.shouldShowPager ? PlasmaCore.Types.ActiveStatus : PlasmaCore.Types.HiddenStatus
```

and change it to

```
Plasmoid.status: pagerModel.shouldShowPager || true ? PlasmaCore.Types.ActiveStatus : PlasmaCore.Types.HiddenStatus
```

This makes `Plasmoid.status` always be `PlasmaCore.Types.ActiveStatus` instead of being set to `PlasmaCore.Types.HiddenStatus` when `pagerModel.shouldShowPager` is false, which is incidentally when there is only one virtual desktop.

Note: This may not persist across updates.